# Numbers in Internationalization (i18n) in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, internationalization, yaml

How can i use numbers in my yml files to show translations?

f.e.:

```
  # de.yml
  profile:
    hair_colour:
      0: "Blond"
      1: "Dunkelblond"
      2: "Braun"
      3: "Brünett"
      4: "Rot"
      5: "Schwarz"
      6: "Grau/meliert"
      7: "Glatze"
      8: "Andere"
```

Its not working... Why? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh ^^

Fixed it with:

```
  # de.yml
  profile:
    hair_colour:
      "0": "Blond"
      "1": "Dunkelblond"
      "2": "Braun"
      "3": "Brünett"
      "4": "Rot"
      "5": "Schwarz"
      "6": "Grau/meliert"
      "7": "Glatze"
      "8": "Andere"
```